# Calculating time range with timedelta & Boolean

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I need help doing a timedelta function to determine if the `actn_dt` is greater than or equal to 1 year ago and if it is, return experienced.

dataframe `f2` looks like this:

```
           nm_emp_lst    actn_dt
14483   MACKENZIE         2015-03-22
132902  CAMPBELL          2015-04-19
124182  SJOSTROM          2015-03-22
103482  LAPLANTE          2014-11-30
45722   LEMAY             2014-11-30
169088  TAYLOR            2015-06-14
105355  HENDERSON         2015-11-01
105359  HENDERSON         2014-10-19
45394   PELLERIN          2015-07-12
119317  BOISSEAU          2015-07-12
```

Should look like this:

```
           nm_emp_lst    actn_dt        Experienced
14483   MACKENZIE         2015-03-22   
132902  CAMPBELL          2015-04-19    
124182  SJOSTROM          2015-03-22
103482  LAPLANTE          2014-11-30    Experienced
45722   LEMAY             2014-11-30    Experienced
169088  TAYLOR            2015-06-14    
105355  HENDERSON         2015-11-01    
105359  HENDERSON         2014-10-19    Experienced
45394   PELLERIN          2015-07-12    
119317  BOISSEAU          2015-07-12
```

So, anything that is equal to or greater than one year ago.

Made a function:

```
year = timedelta(days=365)
today2 = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%A_%B_%d_%Y_%H%M')

def year(row):
    if row['actn_dt'] >= today2 - year:
        return "Experienced"
```

And then lamdba function:

```
f2['Experienced'] = f2.apply (lambda row: year (row),axis=1)
```

From this, I receive the error:

> TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'function'", u'occurred at index 14483')

My dtypes are:

```
nm_emp_lst            object
actn_dt       datetime64[ns]
```

Appreciate any help!

=== UPDATE ===
From the help of jezrael I was able to come up with a solution.  It may have been the long way but it works.  First I had to create a new column that provided data for one year prior to today's date.

```
f2['year1'] = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
```

Then I had to change the 'year1' from a timedelta to datetime:

```
f2['year1'] = pd.to_datetime(f2['year1'], coerce=True)
```

From here I used the coding provided by jezrael.

```
f2.loc[f2['actn_dt'] <= f2['year1'], 'Experienced'] = "Experienced"
```

New results are:

```
               nm_emp_lst    actn_dt      year1  Experienced
14483   MACKENZIE         2015-03-22 2015-02-12          NaN
132902  CAMPBELL          2015-04-19 2015-02-12          NaN
124182  SJOSTROM          2015-03-22 2015-02-12          NaN
103482  LAPLANTE          2014-11-30 2015-02-12  Experienced
45722   LEMAY             2014-11-30 2015-02-12  Experienced
169088  TAYLOR            2015-06-14 2015-02-12          NaN
105355  HENDERSON         2015-11-01 2015-02-12          NaN
105359  HENDERSON         2014-10-19 2015-02-12  Experienced
45394   PELLERIN          2015-07-12 2015-02-12          NaN
119317  BOISSEAU          2015-07-12 2015-02-12          NaN
```

This worked like a charm!  Thanks jezrael!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - second row in `df` was changed for testing:

```
print df
       nm_emp_lst    actn_dt
14483   MACKENZIE 2015-03-22
132902   CAMPBELL 2018-04-19
124182   SJOSTROM 2015-03-22
103482   LAPLANTE 2014-11-30
45722       LEMAY 2014-11-30
169088     TAYLOR 2015-06-14
105355  HENDERSON 2015-11-01
105359  HENDERSON 2014-10-19
45394    PELLERIN 2015-07-12

print datetime.timedelta(days=365)
365 days, 0:00:00

print datetime.datetime.now().date()
2016-02-12

print datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
2015-02-12
```

```
print df['actn_dt'] <= datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
14483     False
132902    False
124182    False
103482     True
45722      True
169088    False
105355    False
105359     True
45394     False
119317    False
Name: actn_dt, dtype: bool

df.loc[df['actn_dt'] <= datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=365) , 'Experienced'] = "Experienced"
print df
       nm_emp_lst    actn_dt  Experienced
14483   MACKENZIE 2015-03-22          NaN
132902   CAMPBELL 2015-04-19          NaN
124182   SJOSTROM 2015-03-22          NaN
103482   LAPLANTE 2014-11-30  Experienced
45722       LEMAY 2014-11-30  Experienced
169088     TAYLOR 2015-06-14          NaN
105355  HENDERSON 2015-11-01          NaN
105359  HENDERSON 2014-10-19  Experienced
45394    PELLERIN 2015-07-12          NaN
119317   BOISSEAU 2015-07-12          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, jezrael!  This is useful, but its not providing the right data in the new column "Experienced".  Not sure if its something I'm doing on this end, but I've got to look one year back from the actn_dt.  If the actn_dt is at least one year or more ago, then experienced.  I tried changing the + to - and still giving me wrong info.

Comment: I edit answer, I hope it helps you. If not, you can add to question recommended output - the best is [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I provided an example of the expected output.  I think I'm writing the 365 days incorrectly but I'm not sure how to 365 and greater.  Or one year and greater.  thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you have to change `>=` to `<=`. But then value `Experienced` in row with `2015-11-01` in your desired output is typo.

Comment: @jezzrael.  Thanks for the input on the typo error.  Too many straight hours working on this I guess.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: For future reference.  How is the expression written when doing two criteria.  So anything other than experienced is 'New'?

Comment: You can use two conditions with brackets and `&` like: `df.loc[(df['a'] <= 1) & ( df['b'] > -10), 'new'] = 'between -10 and 1'`